# Is the first step of most the accepted mechanism of Perkin's reaction correct?

Tags: organic-chemistry

If I am not wrong this is the most accepted mechanism of perkin's reaction:
[image]

In the first step, is the acetate ion basic enough to abstract proton from acetic anhydride?
If yes, I have a counter arguement. It is well known that acetic anhydride doesn't answer iodoform test despite having an acetyl group. It is mainly because, abstraction of proton is not possible as it would produce a unstable carbanion (because of cross conjugation). 
If OH- cannot abstract the proton iodoform rxn. , how could acetate ion which is a weaker base abstract the same proton in Perkin's reaction?

Comment: AcO- in AcOH is a different base to AcO- in aqueous.

Comment: anyway it is weaker than OH- ,Isn't it? If it can abstract the proton then OH- should also be able to.

Comment: It is weaker than OH-  IN WATER

Comment: Exactly ,@waylander ,  and @ anonymous ever heard about alcoholic KOH reagent, and it's use in elimination?

Comment: @Waylander Are you telling AcO- in AcOH is stronger than OH- in AcOH? If yes, could you provide an explanation? And  yes have heard about alcoholic KOH.

Comment: @Waylander: if I understand it correctly, in the aqueous medium, ethanoic acid is readier to donate its proton to a hydroxyl, which makes sense. Did you mean to say this is not the case in pure ethanoic acid? What exactly makes it different?